# Android Upload image on server , image is broken

Tags: php, android, image, upload

i'm using a method "uploadAvatar" to upload an image on my ubuntu server with android 4.1 and php with nginx and php-fpm 5.3. The photo is picked or take from camera and then is cropped , saved in a folder and then uploaded to the server.

I can see the image in the phone at the right path, with the gallery application. I call the method with the absolute path of the image and then the application start to upload the image, the server respond 200, the image is on the server but is broken, i'm unable to read the image with a browser.

```
public int uploadAvatar(String sourceFileUri) {


    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        ProgressDialog_.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename=" + fileName + " + lineEnd");

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        /*
                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                +uploadFileName;

                        //messageText.setText(msg);
                        */

                        Toast.makeText(Register_avatar.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            ProgressDialog_.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(Register_avatar.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            ProgressDialog_.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(Register_avatar.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        ProgressDialog_.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

and this is the server side PHP script:

The image is uploaded but is broken, on the device is ok ...
It's about 2 days i'm working on this issue , somebody can help me ?

you can see the broken image here: http://putp.about42.com/testimage.png

UPDATE:

to build this method i follow the tutorial from [here](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106) :

i found an error in the line :

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
                                         + fileName + """ + lineEnd);
```

and i changed with this :

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename=" + fileName + " + lineEnd");
```

Maybe the broken image depend on this ... i'm sorry but i don't know what this line of code do ...

Thanks

Comment: perhaps this can help you http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Comment: @LatheesanKanes thanks but that is exatly the tutorial i use to build my method :( there was an error dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""+ fileName + """ +lineEnd); and i solved with : dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename=" + fileName + " + lineEnd") But maybe this is the error ... i don't understand what mean this line of code :( some help ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code work fine !

```
public void uploadAvatar(String sourceFileUri) {

    HttpURLConnection mHttpURLConnection = null;
    DataOutputStream mOutputStream = null;
    String strLineEnd = "\r\n";
    String strTwoHyphens = "--";
    String strUpLoadServerUri = upLoadServerUri;
    String strBoundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        ProgressDialog_.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

    }
    else
    {

        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(strUpLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

            mHttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            mHttpURLConnection.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            mHttpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            mHttpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy

            mHttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            mHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");
            mHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE","multipart/form-data");
            mHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=" + strBoundary);
            mHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",sourceFileUri);

            mOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mHttpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

            mOutputStream.writeBytes(strTwoHyphens + strBoundary + strLineEnd);
            mOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename="+ sourceFileUri + strLineEnd);

            mOutputStream.writeBytes(strLineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                mOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            mOutputStream.writeBytes(strLineEnd);
            mOutputStream.writeBytes(strTwoHyphens + strBoundary + strTwoHyphens + strLineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = mHttpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            mOutputStream.flush();
            mOutputStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(),ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception","Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

        Log.d("File Uploaded For ",sourceFileUri + "   Successful");

        ProgressDialog_.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                        /*
                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                +uploadFileName;

                        //messageText.setText(msg);
                        */

                Toast.makeText(Register_avatar.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
    else{
        Log.d("File Uploaded For ",sourceFileUri + "   Failed");
        ProgressDialog_.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                        /*
                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                +uploadFileName;

                        //messageText.setText(msg);
                        */

                Toast.makeText(Register_avatar.this, "File Upload Failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

i made some modification at the code and now it works like a charm!

Bye